# flutter android launch_background.xml file

Tags: flutter

i need an example of launch_background.xml file in android folder that contains and image and (text)...basically my main problem is that i can't place text in this splash screen..so to be specific...i want to achieve splash screen that contains and image and under it there is some text...

i achieved the image preview with bitmap tag inside of an item tag

but no Textview tag can be placed inside layer-list tag :( (not showing)

i know that i can make the text as an svg file and place it in item tag..but i want to do it with TextView tag...so i can control it

any help would be much appreciated...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to give a solution to my own problem... at first I didn't like to place my text inside a separate .png file for the purpose of reducing the apk file size. I placed it inside an svg file for the size purpose but I couldn't place that text in svg beneath the centered image... unless by hardcoding values with the attributes: `"android:gravity=center" "android:top=200dp"` ...and I don't feel comfortable with hardcoded values... so I searched and found this package "flutter_native_splash" [Flutter Native Splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash).

Placed the desired image and beneath it the desired text and the package generated the appropriate image densities for the various screens containing the image and text...